# ArcGIS Server GP Service: How to create a txt file or rename a dbf to txt in the "%SCRATCHWORKSPACE%"

Tags: arcgis-server, arcpy

My end goal is to get an excel (I'll probably just settle for .csv) file loaded from a silverlight app into my "%SCRATCHWORKSPACE%" for my gp service.  I will be linear referencing the data onto a polyline.

I have silverlight reading the csv file's contents and packing it into a string to send over to ArcGIS Server.

Then I want to write this data to a csv file in the "%SCRATCHWORKSPACE%".  But I don't seem to be able to use any standard python code to hit the "%SCRATCHWORKSPACE%".

Any thoughts or critiques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace yields

C:\Users\ARCGIS~\AppData\Local\Temp\geoprocessing\model_gpserver\j7560bf9fcf9844f7a4736d36ea123456\scratch

Which allowed my to use non-arcpy methods targeting the scratch workspace of a gp service job request.

Answer (score 1):

Set an input to your gp service to be the `%scratchworkspace%` - this should get resolved by ArcGIS Server into a actual directory path on disk that (assuming the SOC account has access to the folders) you should be able to write to no worries. It will end up in the `arcgisjobs` folder, in a subfolder under the name of the service, and then under another subfolder that is created by ArcGIS Server on a random text string. e.g.:

```
C:\arcgisserver\arcgisjobs\toolbox\model\j5f4eb1370ded4e8e99a17519c0989850
```

Last tip is that this doesn't get cleaned up automatically, so you'll have to set that up yourself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have no issues writing to the the job folder j5f4eb1370ded4e8e99a17519c0989850\scratch\ folder with arcpy methods but I can't do os.rename(src,dst).  I get an error saying the directory is not found.